# count the max number of _ and add additional ; if missing

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with several fields like below

```
deme_Fort_Email_am;04/02/2015;Deme_Fort_Postal
deme_faible_Email_am;18/02/2015;deme_Faible_Email_Relance_am
equi_Fort_Email_am;23/02/2015;trav_Fort_Email_am
trav_Faible_Email_pm;18/02/2015;trav_Faible_Email_Relance_pm
trav_Fort_Email_am;12/02/2015;Trav_Fort_Postal
voya_Faible_Email_am;29/01/2015;voya_Faible_Email_Relance_am
```

Aim is to have that

```
deme;Fort;Email;am;04/02/2015;Deme;Fort;Postal;;
faible;Email;am;18/02/2015;deme;Faible;Email;Relance;am
Fort;Email;am;23/02/2015;trav;Fort;Email;am;
trav;Faible;Email;pm;18/02/2015;trav;Faible;Email;Relance;pm
trav;Fort;Email;am;12/02/2015;Trav;Fort;Postal
voya;Faible;Email;am;29/01/2015;voya;Faible;Email;Relance;am
```

I'm counting the max of underscore for one of the line then change it to semi-colon and add additional semi-colon, if it is not the maximum number of semi-colon found in all the lines.

I thought about using awk for that but I will only change ,with the command line below , every thing after the first field. My aim is also to add additional semi-colon

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/_/,";", $i) } 1' file
```

Note: As awk is dealing on a line by line basis, I'm not sure I can do that but I'm asking just in case. If it cannot be done, please let me know and I'll try to find another way.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry and thanks @fedorqui. Amended.

Comment: then what you want to do is to replace all `_` with `;`, right? I don't see much logic beyond that

Comment: @fedorqui my question would be to know if it is possible to do so in awk because it would mean to look at the maximum number of _ for any lines and then add additional semi-colon when it has not reached that number. And I have a massive doubt...

Comment: Another awk way `awk -F';' -vOFS=';' '{(y=gsub(/[_;]/,";"))>x&&x=y;for(i=NF+1;i<=x+1;i++)$i=""}NR!=FNR' file{,}`

Comment: @JID, have you tested your solution?

Comment: @AndyK yep why ? Does it not work with your completely changed question and requirements ?

Comment: @JID, indeed apologies. Your solution works fine with my initial sample.

Comment: @JID, do you think you can help me out with my almost new question, please?

Comment: When data change radical, make a new question.

Comment: @Jotne, is that radical? ok -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a two-pass solution. Note you need to put the data file twice on the command line when running awk:

```
$ cat mu.awk
BEGIN { FS="_"; OFS=";" }
NR == FNR { if (max < NF) max = NF; next }
{ $1=$1; i = max; j = NF; while (i-- > j) $0 = $0 OFS }1

$ awk -f mu.awk mu.txt mu.txt
deme;Fort;Email;am;04/02/2015;Deme;Fort;Postal;;
deme;faible;Email;am;18/02/2015;deme;Faible;Email;Relance;am
equi;Fort;Email;am;23/02/2015;trav;Fort;Email;am;
trav;Faible;Email;pm;18/02/2015;trav;Faible;Email;Relance;pm
trav;Fort;Email;am;12/02/2015;Trav;Fort;Postal;;
voya;Faible;Email;am;29/01/2015;voya;Faible;Email;Relance;am
```

The `BEGIN` block sets the input and output file separators.

The `NF == FNR` block makes the first pass through the file, setting the max number of fields.

The last block makes the second pass through the file. First it reconstitutes the line to use the output file separator and than adds an extra `;` for however many fields the line is short of the max.

**EDIT**

This version answers the updated question to only affect fields after field 7:

```
$ cat mu2.awk
BEGIN { OFS=FS=";" }

# First pass, find the max number of "_"
NR == FNR { gsub("[^_]",""); if (max < length()) max = length(); next }

# Second pass:
{
    # count number of "_" less than the max
    line = $0
    gsub("[^_]","", line)
    n = max - length(line)

    # replace "_" with ";" after field 7
    for (i=8; i<=NF; ++i) gsub("_", ";", $i);

    # add an extra ";" for each "_" less than max
    while (n-- > 0) $0 = $0 ";"
}1

$ awk -f mu2.awk mu2.txt mu2.txt
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;deme;Fort;Email;am;04/02/2015;Deme;Fort;Postal;;
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;deme;faible;Email;am;18/02/2015;deme;Faible;Email;Relance;am
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;equi;Fort;Email;am;23/02/2015;trav;Fort;Email;am;
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;trav;Faible;Email;pm;18/02/2015;trav;Faible;Email;Relance;pm
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;trav;Fort;Email;am;12/02/2015;Trav;Fort;Postal;;
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;voya;Faible;Email;am;29/01/2015;voya;Faible;Email;Relance;am
```

Comment: hi @jas, your solution is interesting. However, let's say you want to start the script after the 7th field, where would you amend your script?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, @AndyK. You mean you want to keep the `"_"` character separating the first seven fields in each line, and then switch to `";"`?  (It might be easier if you edit your question to show the new sample output you'd like to see for this case. Do that and I'll definitely take a look at how to modify the solution.)

Comment: there you go @jas. Sorry, I thought it would work even if there were prior fields and that they needed to be untouched.

Comment: @AndyK, see my edit with a proposed solution for the new requirement.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
awk -F_ '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[NR FS i]=$i;c=NF>c?NF:c} END {for (j=1;j<=NR;j++) {for (i=1;i<c;i++) printf "%s;",a[j FS i];print a[j FS c]}}' file
deme;Fort;Email;am;04/02/2015;Deme;Fort;Postal;;
deme;faible;Email;am;18/02/2015;deme;Faible;Email;Relance;am
equi;Fort;Email;am;23/02/2015;trav;Fort;Email;am;
trav;Faible;Email;pm;18/02/2015;trav;Faible;Email;Relance;pm
trav;Fort;Email;am;12/02/2015;Trav;Fort;Postal;;
voya;Faible;Email;am;29/01/2015;voya;Faible;Email;Relance;am
```

How it works:

```
awk -F_ '                               # Set field separator to "_"
    {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)                # Loop trough one by one field
        a[NR FS i]=$i                   # Store the field in array "a" using both row(NR) and column position(i) as referense
    c=NF>c?NF:c}                        # Find the largest number of fields and store it in "c"
END {                                   # When file read is done, then do at end
    for (j=1;j<=NR;j++) {               # Loop trough all row
        for (i=1;i<c;i++)               # Loop trough all column
            printf "%s;",a[j FS i]      # Print one and one field for every row
        print a[j FS c]                 # Print end field in each row
        }
    }
' file                                  # read the file
```

Comment: Hi @Jotne , can you explain a bit, please?

Comment: @andyk It probably doesn't work because you competely changed the question :)

Comment: @Jotne sorry it did work actually. I tried again and now it is fine.

Comment: @AndyK Updated to work with new data.  Just changed field separator.