# count the max number of _ and add additional semi-colon if some are missing

Tags: bash, awk

I have several files with fields like below

```
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;deme_Fort_Email_am;04/02/2015;Deme_Fort_Postal
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;deme_faible_Email_am;18/02/2015;deme_Faible_Email_Relance_am
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;equi_Fort_Email_am;23/02/2015;trav_Fort_Email_am
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;trav_Faible_Email_pm;18/02/2015;trav_Faible_Email_Relance_pm
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;trav_Fort_Email_am;12/02/2015;Trav_Fort_Postal
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;voya_Faible_Email_am;29/01/2015;voya_Faible_Email_Relance_am
```

Aim is to have that

```
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;deme;Fort;Email;am;04/02/2015;Deme;Fort;Postal;;
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxxdeme;faible;Email;am;18/02/2015;deme;Faible;Email;Relance;am
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;equi;Fort;Email;am;23/02/2015;trav;Fort;Email;am;
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;trav;Faible;Email;pm;18/02/2015;trav;Faible;Email;Relance;pm
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;trav;Fort;Email;am;12/02/2015;Trav;Fort;Postal;;
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;voya;Faible;Email;am;29/01/2015;voya;Faible;Email;Relance;am
```

I'm counting the max of underscore, after the 7th field, for any line. I then change it to semi-colon and add additional semi-colon depending of the maximum underscore count found in all the lines.

I thought about using awk for that but I will only change ,with the command line below , every thing after the first field. My aim is also to add additional semi-colon

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {for (i=7;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/_/,";", $i) } 1' file
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are missing two `;` off the end of the fifth line of output

Comment: possible duplicate of [count the max number of \_ and add additional ; if missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938420/count-the-max-number-of-and-add-additional-if-missing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk way

```
awk -F';' -vOFS=';' '{y=0;for(i=8;i<=NF;i++)y+=gsub(/_/,";",$i)
                     x=x<y?y:x;NF=NF+(x-y)}NR!=FNR' file{,}
```

---

#### Output

```
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;deme;Fort;Email;am;04/02/2015;Deme;Fort;Postal;;
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;deme;faible;Email;am;18/02/2015;deme;Faible;Email;Relance;am
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;equi;Fort;Email;am;23/02/2015;trav;Fort;Email;am;
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;trav;Faible;Email;pm;18/02/2015;trav;Faible;Email;Relance;pm
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;trav;Fort;Email;am;12/02/2015;Trav;Fort;Postal;;
xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;x_x_x;xxx;xxx;voya;Faible;Email;am;29/01/2015;voya;Faible;Email;Relance;am
```

---

#### Explanation

```
awk -F';' -vOFS=';'
```

This sets the Field Separator and Output Field separator to `;`.

```
y=0;
```

Initialised y as 0 on each line.

```
for(i=8;i<=NF;i++)y+=gsub(/_/,";",$i)
```

For each field from field 8 to the Number of Fields on the line(`NF`).Substitute `_` with a `;`.Increment y by the number of substitutions.

```
x=x<y?y:x
```

Check if `x` is less than `y`, if it is set `x` to `y`else leave the same.

```
NF=NF+(x-y)
```

Set the number of field to the current number of fields + the difference between x and y.

```
NR!=FNR
```

This means that if the Total record number is not equal to the Files record number then print.Effectively means print anything that isn't the first file.

```
file{,}
```

Expands to `file file` so the file is read twice.

---

#### Resources

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html